# Get URL parameter in controller constructor using Asp Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I using Asp Web Api V1

this is my Route rule

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "FriendsUrl",
    routeTemplate: "api/{alias}/Friends",
    defaults: new 
    { 
        alias = RouteParameter.Optional, 
        controller = "User", 
        action = "Friends" 
    }
);
```

and This is my url example: **/api/Smith/Friends**.
my action works as it should, and I get *alias* as parameter, but I need something more.

I need get that *alias* in controller's constructor

```
public PersonController()
{
    var alias = // alias from url
}
```

The worst version is get url by **HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;**, and parse it, but I don't like that approach because in other route rule the first parameter after `api/` is a controller's name:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ApiByAction",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { action = @"^(?!\d)[a-z0-9]+$" }
);
```

So is there any solution? thanks)

Comment: And why do you need that?

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin It will take long time to explain it, in two words  I need configure my controller for each user, meaning by alias

Comment: May be your architecture is not that optimal then?

Comment: I also don't understand what benefit you get from this. Once you "configure the controller", that configuration will be lost on the next request anyway,

Comment: @DavidG Right, but next request well be for different alias, so it's OK

Comment: So is there way to do this or not?

Comment: But if the next request is for a different alias, why do you need to access it in the controllers constructor?

Comment: @DavidG in each action I return Josn which have some specific data and data of user by alias, so that data I want to get in constructor and initialize that json, instead of calling same function in every single action, its for avoiding code duplicate, any more questions?

Comment: In that case it just sounds like overkill to do this in the constructor. I would put that code in a private function and call it when you need it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71085/discussion-between-artur-keyan-and-davidg).

Comment: If you want to factor out code that should be run for multiple actions, then you should either 1) create a private method on the controller that each action then would call as @ArturKeyan suggests, 2) override the controller's `OnActionExecuting` method, or 3) create custom action filter that you would then decorate any applicable actions with. The controller's constructor is *not* meant for this type of work.